# День города Феодосии

Tags: грамматика

Скажите пожалуйста, как правильно написать - День города Феодосии? Или День города Феодосия? Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Названия городов как правило склоняются, даже если они используются вместе с родовым словом. Поэтому
***День города Феодосии***

Answer (score 0):

Веhеmothus прав: названия городов склоняются.Правильно: День города Феодесии